# Cannot redirect to local asp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am trying to redirect to a local asp page via java script using 
`window. location. replace()` but it does not seem to be working.

It works using `window.location.replace("http://google.com")` but not if I put

```
window.location.replace("http://localhost..
```

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: How is it not working? Do you have a local web server running?

Answer (score 0):

try this, you can use href to redirect on other page or same page.

```
window.location.href="http://google.com";
```

Or

```
window.location.href="http://localhost.."
```

Try this `window.location = "http://www.google.com/"`

Comment: thanks but it seems that if I do not have a .com or similar it will not work - it also works with using an IP address instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use window.location.assign instead..

```
window.location.assign("http://localhost:57040/NewUserRegistration.aspx")
```

It worked for me..